# Export OpenEXR file from Google Colab

Tags: c++, c++11, google-colaboratory, openexr

Right now, I have some code that is storing an OpenEXR file:

```
    FrameBuffer frameBuffer;
    frameBuffer.insert ("G", Slice(FLOAT, (char *)data, sizeof(*data),
                                   sizeof(*data)*width));
    frameBuffer.insert ("Z", Slice(FLOAT, (char *)rangeMod,
                                   sizeof(*rangeMod),
                                   sizeof(*rangeMod)*width));
    file.setFrameBuffer(frameBuffer);
    file.writePixels(height);
```

But how do I export this file out to a Google Drive folder from Colab?

Thank you!